# when want to edit data see last value (no value that i enter now)

Tags: asp.net

I fill textboxes with data that i get from database and put a button on page that user can edit data and click on this button then from code behind i set changes to database

but when i want to send data (for example `txtName.Text` that source value  is "John" and i change it to "Tom") to database i see `txtName.Text` is "John" (means last value no new value)

why?

```
//Load Data
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
      DataSet ds = ....
      txtName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
}

//Update
protected void reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string name=txtName.Text;
     //i change value of txtName.Text but see value as same as value in ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString() that i select from DB
}
```

Comment: How are you saving to your database?

Comment: it's not important, before i save sth to database i see that the value that i enter in textboxes doesn't exist and i see old value

Comment: You need to break the problem apart - is the problem getting the values from the form or storing them in the database? If it's getting them from the form, we don't need to know about the databse but we need to see your form code. If it's storing it in the database, try using hard-coded dummy values instead of a form to remove uncertainty

Comment: i updated question and put code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting the value of the textbox during each request. If you put the code into a `if (!IsPostBack)` then it will work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
          DataSet ds = ....
          txtName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
      }
}

protected void reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string name=txtName.Text;
}
```

If you place a breakpoint in both `Page_Load` and `reg_Click`, then things will become obvious. `Page_Load` is called on every request. In case of the postback (caused by clicking the button), it is called before the button click handler, and will therefore overwrite the (edited) value of the textbox with the original value read from the database.

Answer (score 0):

@Sajjjjjjad - @M4N is correct, you need to use if(!Page.IsPostBack) in "Page_Load". The reason is, Page_Load will hit everytime when you do a post back, so as per your code, when you call the "reg_Click" method, it will first hit the Page_load method followed by "reg_Click" method which will replace your entered value in the text box.

You can have a look at the asp.net page life cycle to understand the page cycle process here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx which will give you more information.

Please let us know if you have any issues.